# Помогите с телеграм ботом, который должен переходить по ссылкам пользователся

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

```
import telebot 


bot = telebot.TeleBot('6823441825:AAHb97rn_-uYygeyPSExXSjcdI2Iy-n8fRo')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
  bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет')

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message:True)
def link(message):
  if message.text.startswitch('http'):
    bot.visit_url(message.text)
    bot.reply_to(message, 'Я зашёл на ссылку')

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

код бота. Мне нужно написать телеграм бота, который будет заходить на ссылки, которые ему будут кидать пользователи. Чатгпт написал, что для данной задачи подойдёт метод bot.visit_url. Я вписал всё, сделал, но во первых ни на какие ссылки он не переходит, во вторых в терминале выдаёт такую ошибку
[image: ошибка]

Comment: не `.startswitch`, а `.startswith`

Answer (score 3):

Замените строку:

```
if message.text.startswitch('http'):
```

На строку:

```
if message.text[:4] == 'http':
```